# SOAP request is working with SOAPClient but not working in PHP

Tags: php

SOAP request is working with SOAP UI but not working in PHP.

```
<?php
$options = array(
        "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,
        "trace"=>1,
       // 'SOAPAction'=>'http://bsestarmf.in/MFOrderEntry/getPassword',
       // 'Action'=>'http://bsestarmf.in/MFOrderEntry/getPassword',
      //  'uri'=>'http://bsestarmf.in/MFOrderEntry/getPassword',
        'exceptions'=>true );

$wsdl   = "http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFOrderEntry/MFOrder.svc?singleWsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,$options);


//$client->__setSoapHeaders($actionHeader);
$request_param=array('UserId'=>"CAFS101", "Password"=>"123456", "PassKey"=>"abc123");

try
{ 

 $return = $client->getPassword($request_param);

 // $xmlstr = $client->Send("$inputxml");

    echo $response_param;

  }
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "<h2>Exception Error!</h2>";
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

> Exception Error!
>   The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'http://bsestarmf.in/MFOrderEntry/getPassword'.

Comment: as per error `getPassword` function doesn't exist in `http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFOrderEntry/MFOrder.svc?singleWsdl` endpoint

Comment: The function exists to use this " var_dump($client->__getTypes());"

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the example how to define e.g. soapaction: https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

```
$client->__soapCall("SomeFunction", array($a, $b, $c),
                array('soapaction' => 'some_action',
                      'uri'        => 'some_uri'));
```

Comment: but you are not doing this in your code example from your starting question. also, look at case sensitivity soapaction